# Factorize a piece of code

Tags: c#, enums

I'm wondering if I can factorize this code:

```
ConsoleKey input = Console.ReadKey().Key;
if (input == up)
    return Action.up;
if (input == down)
    return Action.down;
if (input == left)
    return Action.left;
if (input == right)
    return Action.right;
return Action.none;
```

(Action is an enum (enum Action {up, down, left, right, none}))
Because I repeat approximatively the same 2 lines 4 times...

Thanks for reading!

Comment: i feel like if you're going to ask us to refactor code for you, it should at least compile

Comment: use a `switch` statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define enumeration as follows:

```
enum Action
{
    Up = ConsoleKey.UpArrow,
    Down = ConsoleKey.DownArrow,
    Left = ConsoleKey.LeftArrow,
    Right = ConsoleKey.RightArrow,
    None = 0
}
```

Code might look like this:

```
ConsoleKey input = Console.ReadKey().Key;
var action = (Action)input;

if (!Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Action), action))
    return Action.None;
else
    return action;
```

Answer (score 1):

your looking to do something like this;

```
Enum.TryParse<fun>(Console.ReadKey().Key.ToString(), out val)
```

example;

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        enum fun
        {
            None,
            UpArrow,
            DownArrow,
            LeftArrow,
            RightArrow

        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            fun val = fun.None;

            Console.WriteLine("Start using your arrow key on your keyboard!");

            do
            {
                if (val != fun.None)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(val);
                }
            }
            while (Enum.TryParse<fun>(Console.ReadKey().Key.ToString(), out val));

            Console.WriteLine("Invalid key bye bye");

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to refactor this kind of code, that might look something like this:
replace if conditions with one switch statement and it gonna look smth like this:

```
ConsoleKey input = Console.ReadKey().Key;

switch(input)
{
case "up":return Action.up;
break;
case "down":return Action.down;
break;
case "left":return Action.left;
break;
case "right":return Action.right;
break;
default:
return Action.none;

}
```

Like this your code is more cleaner.
Note :

For just a few items, the difference is small. If you have many items you should definitely use a switch.

Comment: @Soka Toa remember to vote up if you like the answer.

Comment: Please do not add "begging for upvote/accept" notes or comments, it detracts from the value.  If it is good/the best it will get those.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss This was more education thing for a guy who asked question, I saw he had reputation 1 and he just accepted an answer so I told him if he like answer to not forget in future to upvote it ..